# Vue js + Flask + AWS Cognito authentication

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, flask, amazon-cognito

I am learning Vue JS, and understood Vue JS <-> AWS Cognito Auth mechanism and then Vue JS <-> Flask integration.
Now I would like to understand how can I authenticate a user using AWS Cognito using Vue JS as frontend and once authenticated, how can I securely call Flask Backend api's?
How does Flask verify authentication data (like JWT Token provided by AWS Cognito to Vue) provided by Vue JS to respond to API calls?

[image: Simple high level System Design of Vue JS Frontend, Flask Backend and AWS Cognito]

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS API Gateway in front of your Flask app, the API gateway can authorize the JWT token and pass your request to Flask

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33089777)